# Shell File extension for Multiple "."

Tags: shell, unix

I need to extract the file extension for the files in a directory, however the files are in the below format,

```
ab10001i.39400.8163.txt
ab10001i.39400.0433.txt
ab10001i.39400.24433.txt
ab10001i.39400.90631.TXT
```

I tried the below script , but didn't give me the expected results.. Any advise ? thank you!!

```
for file in "$SEARCH_DIR"/*; do
  clmFile=`basename "$file"`
  lastpart=``echo -n ${clmFile%.*} | tail -c4``
  echo "TEST THIS THIS " $lastpart
  if [ ${extension} == "TXT" ]; then
     echo "TXT FILE"
  elif [ ${extension} == "txt" ]; then
     echo "txt FILE"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever set the `extension` variable.

Comment: My bad and found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..

```
lastpart=`echo -n ${clmFile%} | tail -c4
```

this will extract the output as below

```
txt
txt
txt
TXT
```

My Input files

```
ab10001i.39400.8163.txt
ab10001i.39400.0433.txt
ab10001i.39400.24433.txt
ab10001i.39400.90631.TXT
```

Is it a good script practice? Any other suggestions or recommendations?